# If condition does not work in Microchip MPLAB IDE XC8 compiler

Tags: c, mplab, xc8, mplab-x

```
/*
 * File:   proje_6.c
 * Author: ayanoglu
 *
 * Created on 08 Nisan 2023 Cumartesi, 12:14
 */


#include <xc.h>

void delayFunction(unsigned int);

#define Button PORTBbits.RB0   //RB0 button

#define Led PORTBbits.RB1       //RB1 led

char Counter = 0;



void main(void) {
  
    TRISBbits.TRISB0 = 1;
    TRISBbits.TRISB1 = 0;


    
    if (Button==1){
        Counter++;
        
        
        if ((Counter !=0) && (Counter %10 == 0)){
            Led = 1;
            delayFunction(200);
            Led = 0;

        }
        
    }
    while(1);
    
    
    
    
    
}

void delayFunction(unsigned int itime){
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned char j;
    for (i=0;i<itime;i++){
        for(j=0;j<165;j++);
    }
}
```

I use P18F45K22

I want the led to turn on and turn off after a while when the number reaches tens(10,20,30..) but I can't get into the if statement.

pin RB0 as a button and pin RB1 as a led

counter should increase as I press the button

Comment: There isn't an activity loop. The code executes once, and then hangs at `while(1);`. Even if the `if (Button==1)` branch had been taken, then `Counter == 1` and won't satisfy the condition to turn on the LED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need something like:

```
#include <xc.h>
#include <libpic30.h>  //For __delay32(...)

#define Button PORTBbits.RB0   //RB0 button

#define Led PORTBbits.RB1       //RB1 led

void main(void) {
    INT8 Counter = 0; //char can be used on PIC's but nicer with an int  

    TRISBbits.TRISB0 = 1; //Input
    TRISBbits.TRISB1 = 0; //Output

    while(1) { //Loop forever....

     if (Button==1){ //Assuming here that the button toggles, no bounce, etc.

      Counter++;
             
        if ((Counter !=0) && (Counter %10 == 0)){
            Led = 1;
            __delay32(80000); //Delay 20 milliseconds to stabilise power supply 
            //*See note below... 
            Led = 0;

        }
    }    
}
```

*The __delay32() is a Microchip delay function.  The parameter of 80000 was calculated for my system, yours might be different.

Comment: it built succesfully but on proteus the button doesnt work

Comment: It shouldn't really matter but try replacing the PORTBbits.RB0 and PORTBbits.RB1 to LATBbits.LATB0 and LATBbits.LATB1.